# why order by sql it costs so much time

Tags: mysql

the sql like this in mysql

```
SELECT  record.id,
record.create_time AS finishTime,
   record.money,
   record.real_money AS realMoney,
   record.money-record.real_money AS discountMoney,
   record.out_flow_num AS outFlowNum,
   record.user_id AS userId,
   mp_order.order_number AS orderNum,
   mp_order.teacher_id AS teacherId,
   stc.small_type_name AS smallTypeName
  FROM mp_bill_record record 
JOIN
(
    SELECT bill_type, small_type, channel, small_type_name
  FROM mp_bill_small_type_channel
  WHERE type= 'CASH_CONSUME'
  AND is_delete= 0
  AND id= 60) stc
ON record.bill_type= stc.bill_type
AND record.small_type= stc.small_type
AND record.channel= stc.channel
LEFT JOIN mp_order ON record.common_id= mp_order.id
WHERE record.is_delete= 0
AND record.create_time>= '2018-12-24 00:00:00'
AND record.create_time< '2018-12-25 00:00:00'
```

with `ORDER BY record.id  desc`  it cost more than 30000ms. without  `ORDER BY record.id  desc` it cost 300ms.
and, the result  only  has 8 rows.

[the explain  with order by](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zT0O5.png)

[the explain without order by](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SzZvg.png)

Comment: where did you put order by? into the subquery?

Comment: like this `AND record.create_time< '2018-12-25 00:00:00' ORDER BY record.id  desc`

Comment: From EXPLAIN output, it seems you are running MySQL 5.6 or older.  Can you try newer versions?

Comment: MySQL version is 5.6.16. I can not  change the version for this reason. if order by create_time, the sql run 300ms. I  am just curious about it.